# Prolog assign value

Tags: list, prolog, assign

```
a(1). 
a(5).
a(4).
b(1).
b(2).
b(3).
sa(X, Y) :- a(X), Y=a.
sb(X, Y) :- b(X), Y=b.
n([A,B,C], X) :- X=[].
n([A|B],[H|T]):-sa(A,H),n(B,T).
n([A|B],[H|T]):-sb(A,H),n(B,T).
```

and my query:

```
n([1,2,3,4,5],X)
```

results are [a, b] and [b, b].

I am having hard time with [H|T] part, what does it exactly mean. How does X work with [H | T]. I assume that they are somehow both bound to it.

Comment: `[H|T]` is a list where `H` is the first element (the *head*) and `T` is the rest of the list (the *tail*, itself a list). Try the following unification at the Prolog prompt to illustrate: `[1,2,3,4,5] = [H|T]`.

Comment: Another exercise for understanding Prolog unification: define a predicate like so: `list_head_tail([H|T], H, T).`. Then at the Prolog prompt, try the following queries: `list_head_tail([a,b,c], H, T).`, and `list_head_tail(List, 1, [2,3]).` and `list_head_tail([a], H, T).` and `list_head_tail(List, a, []).`.

Comment: Yes, I understand the concept of head and tail, but I dont understand the relationship between input variable X and H|T and how exactly is value [a, b] returned. If you could explain crucial steps to me that'd be awesome.

Comment: Sorry, you said, *I am having hard time with `[H|T]` part, what does it exactly mean.*. Try a `trace`. It's a common recursive list pattern. You're "mapping" `[A|B]` to `[H|T]` by mapping `A` to `B`, then recursively mapping `B` to `T`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, just to simplify a bit, this:

```
sa(X, Y) :- a(X), Y=a.
sb(X, Y) :- b(X), Y=b.
n([A,B,C], X) :- X=[].
```

Can be written as:

```
sa(X, a) :- a(X).
sb(X, b) :- b(X).
n([A,B,C], []).
```

I assume you're having trouble understanding the recursive behavior of the predicate.

By doing `trace` and running a query, you can get a lot of details about what's happening. But we'll try a higher level walk-through.

Consider the query:

```
?- n([1,2,3,4,5],X).
```

You're looking for `X` that makes this true. Prolog will find the first matching predicate clause head for this query. The first `n/2` clause is:

```
n([A,B,C], []).
```

However, the first argument here is a 3-element list, and `[1,2,3,4,5]` is 5 elements. So no match. The next head is:

```
n([A|B], [H|T]) :- sa(A,H), n(B,T).
```

Prolog attempts to unify `[A|B]` with `[1,2,3,4,5]` and succeeds, with `A = 1` and `B = [2,3,4,5]`. It also unifies `X` with `[H|T]` and that also succeeds. So it will call `sa(A,H)` which is a call to `sa(1,H)`. The same process ensues (Prolog matches `sa(1,H)` with the assertions for `sa/2`) and I'll skip the details and just say that the result of that query is `H = a`. You can play with this at the Prolog prompt by entering the query `sa(1,H)` directly to see what the solutions are.

With `H = a`, Prolog's call to `sa(1,H)` has succeeded, and it will then call `n(B,T)` which is `n([2,3,4,5], T)`. Skipping some details, described above, this will map `2` to `b`, and lead to a recursive call `n([3,4,5], T)`. Now `n([3,4,5], T)` matches `n([A,B,C], [])`, so it succeeds with `T = []`. Thus, the recursion in that case has completed and you end up with `X = [a,b]` as a result.

Since Prolog will attempt to find all solutions, it will backtrack to the `sa(1,H)` call and also find `H = b` as a solution, which will ultimately lead to `X = [b,b]`.

I've skipped a lot of steps here, hoping you'll get the idea. Walking through every single step is tedious, which is why I suggest using `trace`.

Comment: So basically X unifies with [H | T], to H is a (H = a) and then only the tail T is used in recursion, right? I assume it works something like T unifies with [H | T], then H = b, so T in the end is b, that's how I understand it. 

Thanks for the answer.

By the way, what does n/2 clause mean?

Comment: @DavosDoe almost.... remember, if you call `n(B, T)` and you have a predicate head that looks like `n([A|B], [H|T])`, the `B` and `T` in `n(B, T)` are not the same `B` and `T` that are in `n([A|B], [H|T])`. So technically, you aren't unifying `T` and `[H|T]` strictly speaking. (This is the same as in C, if you have a function defined with `f(x)` and you call with a variable `f(x)`, it's not the same `x` by name.) I guess you can think of it as `T1` being unified with `[H|T2]` so `T1` becomes decomposted into a head (`H`) and tail (`T2`).

Comment: @DavosDoe `n/2` is notation that means you have a functor `n` with arity 2 (has 2 arguments). If you have found my answer acceptable, then if you don't mind clicking the check mark to accept, I'd be much obliged. :)

Comment: yeah, I got it now, it's basically just X unifies with [H|T], then T unifies with [H1, T1], etc.

I've clicked on the check mark btw, thanks ;)

Comment: @DavosDoe yep, actually `[H1|T1]` not `[H1, T1]`, but I assume that's what you meant. :)